# How to link ftdi d2xx dylib in xcode 11.2?

Tags: xcode, macos, dylib, ftdi, d2xx

I'm trying to get the ftd2xx dylib to work in a MacOS terminal xcode project.

I've installed the driver and the conflict fix for the apple driver correctly as per ReadMe instructions.

https://www.ftdichip.com/Drivers/D2XX/MacOSX/ReadMe.rtf

Xcode Version 11.2 (11B52),

FTD -lftd2xx.1.4.16

I've tried linking binaries, build copy, header path and I can't get it to work.

```
Ld /Users/apple/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MacFTDI-edphxbjofhabfwcpxgpgqsbztemk/Build/Products/Debug/MacFTDI normal x86_64 (in target 'MacFTDI' from project 'MacFTDI')
    cd /Users/apple/Desktop/MacFTDI
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang++ -target x86_64-apple-macos10.15 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk -L/Users/apple/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MacFTDI-edphxbjofhabfwcpxgpgqsbztemk/Build/Products/Debug -F/Users/apple/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MacFTDI-edphxbjofhabfwcpxgpgqsbztemk/Build/Products/Debug -F/usr/local/lib/ -F/Users/apple/Desktop/D2XX/ -filelist /Users/apple/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MacFTDI-edphxbjofhabfwcpxgpgqsbztemk/Build/Intermediates.noindex/MacFTDI.build/Debug/MacFTDI.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/MacFTDI.LinkFileList -Xlinker -object_path_lto -Xlinker /Users/apple/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MacFTDI-edphxbjofhabfwcpxgpgqsbztemk/Build/Intermediates.noindex/MacFTDI.build/Debug/MacFTDI.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/MacFTDI_lto.o -Xlinker -export_dynamic -Xlinker -no_deduplicate -stdlib=libc++ -lftd2xx.1.4.16 -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/apple/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MacFTDI-edphxbjofhabfwcpxgpgqsbztemk/Build/Intermediates.noindex/MacFTDI.build/Debug/MacFTDI.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/MacFTDI_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/apple/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MacFTDI-edphxbjofhabfwcpxgpgqsbztemk/Build/Products/Debug/MacFTDI

ld: library not found for -lftd2xx.1.4.16
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I'm new to the Xcode IDE not new to programming.

It seems there are different reasons this does not work based on xcode version. At least that's according to my research.

Any and all help would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance.